# Optical activity of (1r,3R,5S)-1-methyl-3,5-dipropylcyclohexane (or other long alkyl groups)

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

Consider a cyclohexane with a methyl group at C1 position and a propyl group at C3 and C5 position and each of the first bond bonded to the cyclohexane in alkyl groups has wedge bond. I do not think this can be called a meso compound as the second and third bond of the propyls rotate freely and thus there is no plane of symmetry and it is chiral. Despite of that, some sources tend to regard those two propyls as a single unit that is called as *Pr* and hence the compound is meso. Giving those second and third bond of the propyls with mixed wedge-wedge, wedge-dash, dash-wedge, and dash-dash also give same chemical name as (1r,3R,5S)-1-methyl-3,5-dipropylcyclohexane.

I am wondering if those variants will be chiral or not. Whether those variants are chiral or not, I am also interested in how much is the optical activity of each variant.

Comment: The compound is meso even though there are many conformations of the propyl groups. What ever conformation one propyl group adopts, the other one can adopt. On the other hand, imagine each propyl group having a different conformations making that molecule chiral, frozen in time. But there is another molecule that is its mirror image. These two chiral conformations form a racemic pair....no optical activity. Similarly, the gauche conformations of n-butane form a racemate while the anti conformation has a plane of symmetry.

Comment: Unless rotation is blacked, you have no optical activity.

Comment: Regard less methyl is wedge or dash, if both isopropyl groups are in wedge positions, this compound is meso. The compound is optically active when one isopropyl group is a wedge and the other is a dash.